# vscode python import failure in win10

Tags: python, windows, import, visual-studio-code

I have been using Visual Studio Code to develop some python programs. Modules that I import include `numpy` and `cssutils`. Sometimes VS CODE asked for upgrade that I usually agreed. Then today, VS CODE suddenly cannot find `cssutils`. I and my students checked all the environment variables, path variables, and surveyed the internet, but couldn't find any clue. Some people said it is a VS CODE bug that the authors claimed has been fixed but actually not. Some people suggests adding some declaration to the `launch.json` file and `setting.json`.

We tried all and none worked. We have also shut down the PC and rerun vscode.

Finally, we uninstalled `cssutils` and pip install it again. Then the problem became that `numpy` cannot be imported. Then we tried all the methods listed in the above and surveyed the internet. We also decide to uninstall and reinstall vs code. But none worked.

Can someone help ?

We have tried the following:

1. pip installed numpy
2. pip3 installed numpy
3. pip uninstalled numpy and then pip installed it.
4. We checked the path of the python interpreter in vs code environment settings.
5. We tried adding `@{workspaceRoot}` to the environment attribute in launch file.
6. We tried relaunching vs code.
7. We tried shut down the computer and then powered it on again.
8. We tried to reinstall vs code.

But none of the above worked.

We also tried importing `numpy` in powershell and it worked fine.

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe' 'c:\Users\FARN\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '50166' 'C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/src/CnTaaD.py' '-L'
python 3.x
1.here:  C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
T0, starting testing task:  <CnUserManager.CnUserManagerClass object at 0x000001BAC67866A0>
CnServerConnector: rootDir =  C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
FM cmdLineJsonFilePath: C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\YYYYYYYY.json
try opening file in python 3 in utf8!
try loading json file!
success in loading json file:  <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\YYYYYYY.json' mode='r' encoding='utf8'>
After loading the recorded projects json!
icoPath:  C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\src\pictures\animation\setDefault\logocute64.ico
---[ testerFrankWang02  userRecord already exists!]-------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\FARN\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\FARN\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\FARN\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.8.30787\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\FARN\Documents\LINUX\realtime\PRGM\TaaDPlaygroundClient/src/CnTaaD.py", line 35, in <module>
    CnUserManager.CnUserManagerClass(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\FARN\Documents\LINUX\realtime\PRGM\TaaDPlaygroundClient/src\CnUserManager.py", line 1334, in __init__
    import CnProjectManager
  File "C:\Users\FARN\Documents\LINUX\realtime\PRGM\TaaDPlaygroundClient/src\CnProjectManager.py", line 30, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Did this cause your programs to throw errors when run? or does it just only warn underlining code in red?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I think vscode stopped from execution further.  It asked me to press any key to continue.  Then when I depressed return key, it exited the program execution.

Comment: Do you have python vs code extension installed?

Comment: That must be quite sometime ago.  I think we have done that otherwise we could not have run the project over 2 years. Is there any suggestion for checking in this aspect ?

Comment: Or do I have to install some particular version of python or python extension to work with the current vscode ?

Comment: I think this is related to vs code extension. Try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python and see if it works.

Comment: You don't have to install particular version of python as long as it it 2.7 or >=3.5

Comment: Thanks!
But I found that I have already installed the vscode extension.  
Now the problem seems the same. 
Do I have to adopt anaconda ?  Will that help ?

Comment: I think I got the bug.  
The problem is that I have an "import X" statement inside a method that dynamically imports a module X written by me only when the method is executed. 
This module X then imports numpy and all the other public modules. 
In previous versions of python and vscode, my program runs well. 
But now it seems that python or vscode do not allow this dynamic import to be executed as my expectation.  

Do you think what I said matches the new features of either vscode or python vscode extension ?
Will it be possible if to allow linking to the modules in dynamic imports ?

Comment: Now the problem seems trickier than I thought.
The import cv2 failed in a module X written by me which is imported by another module Y. 
The tricky thing is that if I import X in Y deep near the last line in Y, then the import cv2 in X failed. 
But if I import X in Y a litte bit up front, the import cv2 in X made no fuss. 
Can you check when did you all the environment variable and module location binding in your parser ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an installation of Python from Visual Studio instead of your own installed copy. Is that on purpose? And is that the installation of Python you installed numpy into?

The easiest way to see if numpy was installed where you expected is to run `& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe' '-m' 'pip' 'list'` (that quoting might be wrong, but basically you want `-m pip list` passed to the Python interpreter). That will list what pip has installed.

The best solution to this is to use a virtual environment and install into that.